# Django photologue return image urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django-photologue (https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue/tree/master/photologue) to manage images in my project. I have a view that ideally should return urls of the images in a specific gallery.

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_gallery(request, id):
    gallery = Gallery.objects.get(id=id)
    data = []

    for photo in gallery.sample():
        data.append(photo.image)    
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

HttpResponse gives me:

```
photologue/photos/superman_PucGOkm.jpgphotologue/photos/spiderman.png
```

This doesn't look too promising.

Response gives me those long jpg symbols like ¶³”Cé3J<8€ÿ.

What is the correct way of returning such urls, so that I can conveniently handle them on my angular2 frontend? I would then hit those urls from frontend to fetch actual images.

Comment: Please add your `Gallery` model with `methods`

Comment: Well it's a library I am using and its not directly my model, the link I have in my question. Should I still add explicitly that here?

Comment: That looks correct to me? You return a response that just renders out all the urls?

Comment: My goal was to somehow return images to frontend, so earlier I was returning base64 string and was rendering images from that on frontend. Meanwhile I found photo.image that gives me image urls and I thought I do not need overhead of base64

Comment: So what isn't working? your view is doing exactly that? Just return the data in a more stuctured format as per docs

Comment: Yes I guess that's what I wanted, a structured response. Could you perhaps give some hints in answer?